# What elements don't observe the octet rule?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Apart from hydrogen which forms a duet, which element's don't observe the octet rule?

Comment: I plugged your question into google and [this is what I got](http://chemed.chem.wisc.edu/chempaths/GenChem-Textbook/Exceptions-to-the-Octet-Rule-573.html) as the first link.  Do you need something more than this description?

Comment: I was hoping for a list rather than long descriptions..

Comment: see also [ChemWiki:Violations of the Octet Rule](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Theoretical_Chemistry/Chemical_Bonding/Lewis_Theory_of_Bonding/Violations_of_the_Octet_Rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octet rule is more advisory than a rule; It's usually obeyed by the main group elements.
Exception are paramagnetic compounds (obvious reason); first for elements in periodic system (He-configuration), 3-valent boron compounds; depending on counting system boron clusters (f.e. dodecaborane with 6-coordianted boron); transition metal complexes (these usually follow 18e rule, however there are plenty of examples with 14, 16 or even 20 electron complexes).

Comment: It would be nice if you give some examples for TM-complexes not obeying 18e rule.

Comment: Enough that you look at the metallocenes. 15e: VCp2 (Cp=C5H5-); 16e:   
CrCp2; 17e: MnCp'2 (Cp'=C5H4Me-); 19e: CoCp2; 20e: NiCp2. Most of them   
are commercial products.