# Is ClH7 possible?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hybridization, oxidation-state

Chlorine can be $sp^3d^3$ hybridized.

If so, it can form $\ce{ClH_7}$ and then chlorine, being more electronegative, will have (-7) as its oxidation number. But we know that the oxidation number of $\ce{Cl}$ lies between (-1) and (+7).

Thoughts?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/444/can-an-atom-have-more-than-8-valence-electrons-if-not-why-is-8-the-limit

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31584/on-the-geometry-of-sp3d-and-sp3d3-hybridization

Comment: I would not be so quick to dismiss the existence of [other hydrogen chlorides](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2017/cp/c6cp08708f#!divAbstract).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on a skewed premise, as gsurfer04 already pointed out. Rather than invoking d-orbitals, which are usually rather far away in energy from the corresponding p-orbitals (in fact, usually higher in energy than the next shell’s s-orbital, so for chlorine 3p → 4s → 3d), these hypervalent halogen compounds are considered to derive from multi-centre bonds.

For details in the bonding mechanism, I am going to forward you to [this excellent answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18544/7475).

I haven’t seen any multi-hydrogen chloride yet. In fact, when discussing interhalogens like $\ce{ClF3}$, our professor in the introductory chemistry course went as far as saying even $\ce{H3Cl}$ is impossible. I’ve forgotten the exact reasoning (and unfortunately it’s not explicitly stated in the web material any more) but I believe it to be along the lines of hydrogen’s s-orbitals not being able to form the outside parts of a four-electron three-centre bond.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $d$ orbitals play no part in hypervalency.

If you look at existing hypervalent molecules, you'll see that the central atom is always less electronegative. As H is less electronegative than $\ce{Cl}$, $\ce{ClH7}$ will be very unstable.

Comment: The central atom isn't always less electron negative http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00293a020 and http://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja961081v

Comment: @DavePhD Fascinating find on the triprotonated methane! Thanks for the link.

Comment: @DavePhD Although the central atom isn't necessarily less electronegative, in order for the molecule to have 3c-4e bonds, theoretically, the peripheral atoms should be electronegative atoms to withdraw electron density away from the central atom. After all, two of the electrons of the 4 electrons in the 3c-4e bond becomes a lone pair on the peripheral atoms.